# How to interpolate without missing values?

Tags: python, interpolation

I need to interpolate my data not because of missing values but to create new data points and expand my time series. In my final data i need `300` data points. The new data should be between the existing (get a data point between 1 and 2 and at the end of the dataframe) Is there a function to do that?

```
       x        y         z           timestamp
0  0.912956 -1.027331 -0.645289     1649001565984
1 -0.012292 -1.145001  0.092476     1649001565850
2  1.510848 -0.709704 -0.043249     1649001565721
3  1.231071  1.419836  0.576115     1649001565588
4  0.135664  0.981124  0.405955     1649001565457
(182, 4)
```

The expected output is in form:

```
      x         y         z           timestamp
0  0.912956 -1.027331 -0.645289     1649001565984
1 -0.012292 -1.145001  0.092476     1649001565850
2    new_x     new_y    new_z          new_time
3  1.510848 -0.709704 -0.043249     1649001565721
4  1.231071  1.419836  0.576115     1649001565588
5  0.135664  0.981124  0.405955     1649001565457

(300, 4)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get a data point between 1 and 2 and at the end of the dataframe"? What is your expected output?

Comment: @not_speshal sorry I could answer in comments so i edited my question. hope this help

Comment: If you already have a method to interpolate based on missing values, perhaps you can simply insert the required number of null lines where you want them, and then interpolate from there~

Comment: Since you can refer to a time-based index, you can use `pandas.resample`. have a look at the doc https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas.DataFrame.resample

Comment: @Buzz So I should first upsamle my time series and then fill interpolate with new values?\

Comment: It's a way, and you can use `interpolate` to achieve the second step (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.Dataframe() # your definition goes here

new_timestamp = 1649001565800
new_row = [
    np.interp(new_timestamp, df['timestamp'], df['x']),
    np.interp(new_timestamp, df['timestamp'], df['y']),
    np.interp(new_timestamp, df['timestamp'], df['z']),
    new_timestamp
]
df.loc[-1] = new_row # insert new row
df = df.sort_values(by=['timestamp'], ascending=False)  # resort it
```

Comment: This work perfectly to add one new row but manually. In my case i should not add the timestamps manually and I also need it for ```300 - 182 = 118``` data points. It could work if i loop over a list with 118 timestamps but again this way i should choose the timestamps manually. Any ideas?